# How can I compare Date And time using This format HH.mm MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: vb.net

This Format represents 
HH - Hours
.  - Decimal point
mm - Minutes
MM - Month
dd - Day
yyyy - year

The logic will be, The First Priority condition is The date which is MM/dd/YYYY and Second priority is time using HH.mm

My Code:

```
If (Format(CDate(Strings.Right(TextBox9.Text.Trim, 11)))) > (Format(CDate(Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11)))) Then
                TimeError.ShowDialog()
end if
```

I want to make my condition date and time, not date only. please help me.....

Comment: Why should you use such a **funny** format for comparisons? Transform your strings to DateTimes, do the comparisons you need and then display the result in the format you prefer...

Comment: data can be in one form for the code to do things (like a data compare) and formatted for the user differently.  the part of the problem is that you are using UI controls as variables.